# Left margin in my navbar links that won't disappear

Tags: css, html-lists, navbar, margin

I Apologise in advance, but I've searched this website (and google) for hours and can't find a solution. I'm working on this Freecodecamp project.

https://codepen.io/alex1014/pen/XWMaEGg

Problem is: in my navbar (pink), the 3 links are not positioned all the way to the left in the same way the text PREMIUM TROMBONES (in the red div) is... they are slightly pushed towards the centre. It looks like there is some type of margin left, and I can't figure out where it's coming from since I've set to 0 every html/browser default margin.

I have also noticed, that if I text-align: right the links will perfectly go all the way to the right... but if I align left, there will still be margins...

```css
* {
margin: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {  
  background: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
 }

#container {
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

header {
  background-color: cyan;
}

#logo {
  background-color: red;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: pink;
}

ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 list-style-type: none;
 background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  
<header id="header">
  <div id="logo"><h3>Premium Trombones</h3></div>
   <nav id="navbar">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#submit-form">Subscribe</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section1">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section3">Products</a></li>
     </ul> 
  </nav>
</header> 
...
...
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`ul` elements have padding, add:

```
ul {
  padding: 0;
}
```

That should remove the indentation.

Comment: It didn't work for me, however, I have put padding: 0 to the universal selector '*' instead, and it worked perfectly! Thank you so much!